# How do I change the variable value in a different file in Swiftui

Tags: variables, swiftui

I set a variable in the contentview `@State var shouldShowModal = false`, i want to change it once i press a button `shouldShowModal = false`. I keep getting Cannot find 'shouldShowModal' in scope.

Comment: You'll have to show more code than this for a concrete suggestion. In general, I'd read up on `@Binding` and how to pass it between views: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/what-is-the-binding-property-wrapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example, passing the value through `@Binding`s. Read more about `@Binding` [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/what-is-the-binding-property-wrapper), or the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding).

This means that you can now do `shouldShowModal = false` with the binding, which will also update the body of the original view containing `@State`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var shouldShowModal = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello world!")
                .sheet(isPresented: $shouldShowModal) {
                    Text("Modal")
                }
            
            OtherView(shouldShowModal: $shouldShowModal)
        }
    }
}


struct OtherView: View {
    
    @Binding var shouldShowModal: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Should show modal: \(shouldShowModal ? "yes" : "no")")
            
            Toggle("Toggle modal", isOn: $shouldShowModal)
        }
    }
}
```